# .htaccess multiple rewrites for same url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite url
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)/(.*) /beheer/dashboard.php?m=$1&f=$2
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /beheer/dashboard.php?m=$1&f=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

When I try to go to `mydomain.com/beheer/dashboard/test/test` I'm redirected to the normal url of `mydomain.com/beheer/dashboard.php?m=test&f=test` (When I only use the first rewrite else I get 404 error). It might be interesting to know that for some links I also need to pass a third parameter. So for example: `mydomain.com/beheer/dashboard.php?m=user&f=delete&id=1`. So my question is why isn't this .htaccess file working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use end anchor `$` in your regex:

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite url
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beheer/dashboard.php?m=$1&f=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /beheer/dashboard.php?m=$1&f=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```